# How to downgrade rayshader?

Tags: r, rayshader

I want to downgrade version rayshader in R. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thank you.

i try this code, but i think i do something wrong.

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayshader", version = "0.31.0")
```

and

```
install_version("rayshader", version = "0.31.0", repos = "https://api.github.com/users/tylermorganwall/repos")
```

Comment: If you had an earlier version I would have called `remove.packages` first. But I should ask "WHY" do you think you did something wrong. Did you (1) get an error message or (2) a warning message or (3) did the downgrade just not succeed? On SO is it important to include the full text of any warnings or error messages.

Comment: The result of the installation is the latest version.

Comment: Do you see documentation that says `version` is a parameter for that function?

Comment: in `install_version()` use parameter `version`. i don't know in `install_github()`

Comment: It was not  I looked at the current documentation for `install_github` and the function that is documented as being called to handle the "dots" optional arguments. I was attempting to get the OP to learn to read the help pages and understand that they could not expect a warning for a non-existent argument.